# How can I implement a switch user function in Seam?

Tags: security, spring, seam, switch-statement

Spring security provides this switch user feature which I used in previous projects. I checked the document of Seam 2.2.0.GA and found a RunAsOperation class for this purpose, but how can I implement a switch user function (something like `su - <username>` in linux) using Seam Security?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a RunAs block and addRole to acomplish that, just like:

```
new RunAsOperation() {
        public void execute() {
            identityManager.createUser(user.getEmail(), user.getSenha(), user.getNome(), "");
            identityManager.grantRole(user.getEmail(), "ROLE_1");
            identityManager.grantRole(user.getEmail(), "ROLE_2");
        }
}.addRole("admin").run();
```

[]S

Comment: Thanks, Marcos. What I need is to switching to an existing user, for example switching from a admin user to a manager user, then the admin can act as the manager to do what the manager can do and the admin can switch back as he wants. Any suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: All you need is to adapt this code for your needs. In the specific case u mentioned all you need to do is give Admin the grantRole of a Manager.

Answer (score 1):

@Marcos Maia is right. You do not switch users in Seam to run certain operations. You use `RunAsOperation` to temporarily allow higher privileges with roles. There is even a way to bypass any security constraints by running operations as system user:

```
new RunAsOperation(true) {
    public void execute() {
        // operations as system user
    }
}.run();
```

(notice the `true` value in the constructor).

So, if you need to perform some operations as another user, you should definitely use the `RunAsOperation` as suggested by @Marcos Maia.